# Testing Cloud Functions for Firebase with Jasmine and Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, jasmine, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently investigating Google Cloud Functions and have some basic test functions written in typescript.

The functions work as expected and I am now attempting to create unit tests using Jasmine. (I'm not using Chai/sinon as per the docs as the rest of my project uses jasmine).

I have two issues
1) the test does not run due to this error

> throw new Error('Firebase config variables are not available. ' +
>           ^
>   Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the
>   latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function

2) Given the test did run, I'm not sure how to test that the response is as expected.

Index file

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

import { helloWorldHandler } from  './functions/hello-world';

export let helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    helloWorldHandler(req, res);
});
```

File under test

```
export let helloWorldHandler = (request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase Cloud!");
}
```

Spec

```
import {} from 'jasmine';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { helloWorldHandler } from './hello-world';
import * as endpoints from '../index';

describe('Cloud Functions : Hello World', () => {

    let configStub = {
        firebase: {
            databaseURL: "https://myProject.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "myProject.appspot.com",
        }
    };

    it('should return correct message', () => {

        let spy = spyOn(functions, 'config').and.returnValue(configStub);

        const expected = 'Hello from Firebase Cloud!';
        // A fake request and response objects
        const req : any = {};
        const res : any = { };

        endpoints.helloWorld(req, res);

         //here test response from helloWorld is as expected

      });


});
```

Comment: Note that you can now [run Functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) via the emulator, which is some help for testing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are writing unit tests, then you don't want to test third party APIs. Thus, the goal should be to isolate your code logic and test that. End-to-end tests are best suited for regression testing your integrations.

So the first step here would be to remove tools like `firebase-functions` and the Database SDKs from the picture (as much as this is reasonable). I accomplished this by separating my libs from the functions logic like so:

```
// functions/lib/http.js
exports.httpFunction = (req, res) => {
   res.send(`Hello ${req.data.foo}`);
};

// functions/index.js
const http = require('lib/http');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// we have decoupled the Functions invocation from the method
// so the method can be tested without including the functions lib!
functions.https.onRequest(http.httpFunction);
```

Now I have nicely isolated logic that I can test via a unit test. I mock any arguments that would be passed into my methods, removing third party APIs from the picture.

So here's what my unit tests in Jasmine look like:

```
// spec/lib/http.spec.js
const http = require('../functions/lib/http');

describe('functions/lib/http', () => {
   expect('send to be called with "hello world"', () => {
      // first thing to do is mock req and res objects
      const req = {data: {foo: 'world'}};
      const res = {send: (s) => {});

      // now let's monitor res.send to make sure it gets called
      spyOn(res, 'send').and.callThrough();

      // now run it
      http.httpFunction(req, res);

      // new test it
      expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Hello world");
   });
});
```

There are a lot of complexities with testing third party libs. The best answer here to apply TDD/BDD principles early and abstract third party libs into services that can easily be mocked.

For example, if I were interacting with Firebase Admin within my functions, I could easily end up with a method that has lots of third party dependencies to contend with:

```
// functions/lib/http.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const env = require('./env');
const serviceAccount = require(env.serviceAccountPath);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: `https://${env.dbUrl}.firebaseio.com`
});

exports.httpFunction = (req, res) => {
   let path = null;
   let data = null;

   // this is what I really want to test--my logic!
   if( req.query.foo ) {
      path = 'foo';
      data = 1;
   }

   // but there's this third library party coupling :(
   if( path !== null ) {
     let ref = admin.database.ref().child(path);
     return ref.set(data)
        .then(() => res.send('done'))
        .catch(e => res.status(500).send(e));
   }
   else {
      res.status(500).send('invalid query');
   }
};
```

To test this example, I have to include and initialize Functions as well as the Firebase Admin SDK, or I have to find a way to mock those services. All of this looks like a pretty big job. Instead, I can have a DataStore abstraction and utilize that:

```
// An interface for the DataStore abstraction
// This is where my Firebase logic would go, neatly packaged
// and decoupled
class DataStore {
   set: (path, data) => {
      // This is the home for admin.database.ref(path).set(data);
   }
}

// An interface for the HTTPS abstraction
class ResponseHandler {
   success: (message) => { /* res.send(message); */ }
   fail: (error) => { /* res.status(500).send(error); */ } 
}
```

If I now add in the first principle of abstracting my logic from the Functions process, then I have a layout like the following:

```
// functions/lib/http.js
exports.httpFunction = (query, responseHandler, dataStore) => {
   if( query.foo ) {
      return dataStore.set('foo', 1)
        .then(() => responseHandler.success())
        .catch(e => responseHandler.fail(e));
   }
   else {
      responseHandler.fail('invalid query');
   }
};
```

Allowing me to write a unit test that's much more elegant:

```
// spec/lib/http
describe('functions/lib/http', () => {
   expect('is successful if "foo" parameter is passed', () => {
      // first thing to do is mock req and res objects
      const query = {foo: 'bar'};
      const responseHandler = {success: () => {}, fail: () => {});
      const dataStore = {set: () => {return Promise.resolve()}};

      // now let's monitor the results
      spyOn(responseHandler, 'success');

      // now run it
      http.httpFunction(query, responseHandler, dataStore);

      // new test it
      expect(res.success).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

And the remainder of my code isn't half bad either:

```
// functions/lib/firebase.datastore.js
// A centralized place for our third party lib!
// Less mocking and e2e testing!
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require(env.serviceAccountPath);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: `https://${env.dbUrl}.firebaseio.com`
});

exports.set = (path, data) => {
  return admin.database.ref(path).set(data);
};

// functions/index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const dataStore = require('./lib/firebase.datastore');
const ResponseHandler = require('./lib/express.responseHandler');
const env = require('./env');
const http = require('./lib/http');

dataStore.initialize(env);

exports.httpFunction = (req, res) => {
   const handler = new ResponseHandler(res);
   return http.httpFunction(req.query, handler, dataStore);
};
```

Not to mention that beginning with a good BDD mindset, I've also nicely isolated the components of my project in a modular way that's going to be nice when we find out about all the scope creep in phase 2. :)